# Get values from dynamic list and return them as a string

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I am working on a project where a user is going to select a document and it will be placed into a dynamic and sortable list.  The list items will have a value of the specific document's id.  Once the lists are arranged the user is to click Create List and I would like to use Ajax and classic ASP (required for a couple queires that need to occur during this process to grab the new string format) to grab the just the values of the list items and put them into an array.

Here is my list currently:

```
<ul class="main_doc_list">
  <li><b>Editor's Blog</b>
  <ul class="doc_list">
      <li value="111111">Doc Title</li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><b>Blog Roll</b>
    <ul class="doc_list">
      <li value="222222">Doc Title</li>
      <li value="333333">Doc Title 2</li>
      <li value="444444">Doc Title 2</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

And I currently have this in JQuery to trigger the Ajax event.

```
$("#create").click(function() {
    $.ajax(
            {
            type: "GET",
            url: "newslettercreate_action.asp",
            success: function(result) {
                var newsletter_string = $(result);
                $("#scratch").val(newsletter_string);
            }
        });

    })
```

Just not sure that once in my ASP action file how to obtain the values I need to begin the function of building the newsleter_string.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I could not understand what are you having problems with. What exactly is your problem? What is the spected result?

Comment: I don't know how to use ASP to get the values from my list items.  The expected result should be 111111,222222,333333,444444

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Porco have pointed, you can grab this with jQuery itself before posting, you just have to loop trough each element and concatenate the values to post it like Porco said:

```
$("#create").click(function() {
    // get some data 
    var strDocIDs = "";
    $('.main_doc_list').find('li[value]').each(function() {
        strDocIDs += ", " + $(this).attr('value');
    });

    if (strDocIDs != "") alert(strDocIDs.substring(2)); // substring here rips off the first comma
})
```

To post the data, do what Porco have showed you and you can grab the results on ASP as a Request variable:

```
strDocIDs = Request("strDocIDs")
```

Comment: var strDocIDs = $.map($('.main_doc_list').find('li[value]'), function(li) { return $(li).attr("value") }).join(","); if you want

Comment: A good example, but not so easy for a starter to understand, so I've opted for the `each` method, that seems clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Just need to pass in some data:

```
$("#create").click(function() {

    // get some data
    var strDocIDs = $('.main_doc_list').find('li').first().attr('value');

    $.ajax(
            {
            type: "GET",
            url: "newslettercreate_action.asp",
            data: { "'strDocIDs':'" + strDocIDs + "'}",
            success: function(result) {
                var newsletter_string = $(result);
                $("#scratch").val(newsletter_string);
            }
    });

})
```

Comment: I only grab the first DocID, but I hope you are able to write the simple loop to grab them all.

Comment: Thanks.  Writing the loop won't be an issue.  Now, in my ASP action page, how would I reference strDocIDs?

Comment: they will be added on as a request param (so pull them out of the Request object)

Comment: This code will post only the first li value. You will need to loop trough the elements to get all the values. Seel my answer for reference.

Comment: I have still been unable to pass the value into my ASP document.  The data line provided actually breaks the page.  I've played around with it but my ASP document just received all the field names from the form and not the list values.